# Is there a way to comment MS Access queries in the body of the query?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253446/how-do-you-comment-an-ms-access-query) thread and the answers provided indicated to use the 'Description' property of the query to add a comment on the query. This was for Access 2007 at the newest. I'm using 2010 and have tried many different operators for comments (and a bit of googling) to no avail.

I have written a bunch of long-winded queries and need to comment them to indicate the reasons that these similar queries are returning different data.

Is there **any** way to add in-line comments in the SQL of the query objects?

Answer (score 4):

Access SQL does not support SQL comments.  The closest you can do is something like this ... which is ugly.

```sql
SELECT
    'your comment here' AS comment,
    id,
    fld2
FROM YourTable;
```

The *comment* is then a field expression which is included in every row.

Answer (score 0):

I create another Access table called MyComments and put them in there.