# Putting in line comments in sql view for Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to figure out how to put in line comments in Access.
I have seen the below post and have been trying to put through the solution from Dan which includes the WHERE Clause however it comes up with a "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression `AND "Comment FYI, This is a comment"<>""`.

Script I have put through below for reference:

```
SELECT prod_name 
FROM products
WHERE
AND "Comment: FYI, This is a comment"<>"";
```

[How do you comment an MS-access Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253446/how-do-you-comment-an-ms-access-query)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28096339/3820271) assumes that there is something else in the WHERE clause.

If there isn't, you would simply do:

```
SELECT prod_name 
FROM products
WHERE "Comment: FYI, This is a comment"<>"";
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Makes sense now, the AND bit is to add the comment if there is another thing going on.